# Error Installing Certificate when selecting through openFileDialog (possible bug?)

Tags: wix, wix4

Okay so I decided to make a nice little selector when installing certificates that will let you select your .PFX file and input the password for it and later install it. I configured everything nicely but for some reason the certificate installation fails and the log only gives me "InstallCertificates:  Error 0x80070057: Invalid Certificate.Attributes.
InstallCertificates:  Error 0x80070057: Failed to resolve certificate: Cert9" Which doesn't help at all and I'm pretty sure I defined everything correctly I've been staring at it for like an hour already...

Here's all the code below: First the Components file

````
```<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs"
     xmlns:Iis="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/iis">
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="ExampleComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" >
            
            
            
            
            
            <Component Guid="{4041718E-C792-44C5-96C0-487C332873AD}" Id="DzonsoneLLa">
                <Iis:Certificate Id="Cert1"   StoreLocation="localMachine" BinaryRef="Dzonsonella3"
                                 StoreName="ca" Name="Kreditni biro UBS 2020.cer" Vital="no" Request="no" >
                </Iis:Certificate>
                <Iis:Certificate Id="Cert2" BinaryRef="Dzonsonella1" StoreLocation="localMachine"
                                 StoreName="ca" Name="Kreditni Biro UBS N.cer" Vital="no" Request="no">
                </Iis:Certificate>
                <Iis:Certificate Id="Cert3" BinaryRef="Dzonsonella2" StoreLocation="localMachine"
                                 StoreName="ca" Name="Kreditni Biro UBS(3).cer" Vital="no" Request="no">
                </Iis:Certificate>
                <Iis:Certificate Id="Cert4" BinaryRef="Dzonsonella4"  StoreLocation="localMachine"
                                 StoreName="root" Name="UBSCAR N.cer" Vital="no" Request="no">
                </Iis:Certificate>
                <Iis:Certificate Id="Cert5" BinaryRef="Dzonsonella5"  StoreLocation="localMachine"
                                 StoreName="root" Name="ubscar.cer" Vital="no" Request="no">
                </Iis:Certificate>
                <Iis:Certificate Id="Cert6" BinaryRef="Dzonsonella6"  StoreLocation="localMachine"
                                 StoreName="ca" Name="UBSICAINF 2020.cer" Vital="no" Request="no">
                </Iis:Certificate>
                <Iis:Certificate Id="Cert7" BinaryRef="Dzonsonella7" StoreLocation="localMachine"
                                 StoreName="ca" Name="UBSICAINF N.cer" Vital="no" Request="no">
                </Iis:Certificate>
                <Iis:Certificate Id="Cert8" BinaryRef="Dzonsonella8"  StoreLocation="localMachine"
                                 StoreName="ca" Name="UBSICAINF(3).cer" Vital="no" Request="no">
                </Iis:Certificate>
                <Iis:Certificate Id="Cert9" StoreLocation="localMachine" CertificatePath="[FILEPATH]" Name="[IME]"
                                 StoreName="ca"  Vital="yes" PFXPassword="[PFXSIFRA]" Request="no"  >
                </Iis:Certificate>

                    
                
            </Component>
                
            
            
        </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
</Wix> ```




Here's the Dialogue I made for selecting the file and writing the password :


```<!-- Copyright (c) .NET Foundation and contributors. All rights reserved. Licensed under the Microsoft Reciprocal License. See LICENSE.TXT file in the project root for full license information. -->


<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs">
    <Fragment>
        <UI>
            <Dialog Id="WelcomeDlg2" Width="370" Height="270" Title="!(loc.WelcomeDlg_Title)" >
                <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUINext)">
                    <Publish Property="WixUI_InstallMode" Value="Update" Condition="Installed AND PATCH" />
                </Control>
                <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUICancel)">
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg" />
                </Control>
                <Control Id="Bitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="234" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.WelcomeDlgBitmap)" />
                <Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton" X="180" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Disabled="no" Text="!(loc.WixUIBack)" />
                <Control Id="BottomLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="234" Width="370" Height="0" />
                <Control Id="Description" Type="Text"  X="77" Y="200" Width="220" Height="60" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" ShowCondition="NOT Installed OR NOT PATCH" HideCondition="Installed AND PATCH" />
                <Control Id="PatchDescription" Type="Text" X="135" Y="80" Width="220" Height="60" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.WelcomeUpdateDlgDescriptionUpdate)" ShowCondition="Installed AND PATCH" HideCondition="NOT Installed OR NOT PATCH" />
                <Control Id="Title" Type="Text" X="53" Y="30" Width="400" Height="60" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes"  />
                <Control Id="SelektPFXText" Type="Text" X="100" Y="30" Width="290" Height="13" NoPrefix="yes" Transparent ="yes" Text="{\White7}Molim Vas selektujte željeni .PFX fajl" />
                <Control Id="BrowseButton" Type="PushButton" X="278" Y="50" Width="56" Height="17" Text="Browse...">
                    <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="Custom"></Publish>
                    <Publish Property="FILEPATH" Value="[FILEPATH]"/>
                    <Publish Property="IME" Value="[IME]"/>
                </Control>
                <Control Id="PutanjaDoPFX" Type="Text" Text="[FILEPATH]" X="45" Y="50" Width="233" Height="17" Property="FILEPATH"/>
                <Control Id="UnosPFXSifreText" Type="Text" X="100" Y="170" Width="290" Height="13" NoPrefix="yes" Transparent ="yes" Text="{\White7}Molim Vas unesite šifru za Vaš .PFX fajl" />
                <Control Id="UnosPFXSifre" Type="Edit" X="45" Y="182" Width="290" Height="18" Property="PFXSIFRA" Password="yes" />
              
            </Dialog>

            <InstallUISequence>
                <!--<Show Dialog="WelcomeDlg2" Before="ProgressDlg" Overridable="yes" Condition="NOT Installed OR PATCH" />-->
            </InstallUISequence>
        </UI>
    </Fragment>
</Wix> 

 Here's my Package file too




<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs"
     xmlns:ui="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/ui"
     xmlns:powershell="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/powershell"
     xmlns:Iis="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/iis">


    
    
    <?if $(var.Platform)=x64 ?>
    <?define ProductCode = "{0F7564E3-56A2-447C-BDA1-8A0D38A0DD5E}"?>
    <?else?>
    <?define ProductCode = "{B304F287-8D2A-4233-8F47-D2D3FD8B07C7}"?>
    <?endif?>
    
    <?define UpgradeCode = "{1E6CD331-2C24-468D-AB2A-6CC0A40B8909}"?>

    <?define BuildVersion = 1.0.0?> 
    
  <Package Name="!(loc.ProductName_$(var.Platform))"
           Manufacturer="!(loc.Company)"
           Version="$(var.BuildVersion)"
           UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)">

      <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />
      
      <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="!(loc.DowngradeError)" />
      <Icon Id="B2BAdminIkonica.exe" SourceFile="$(var.ProjectDir)/Assets/KB_icon1.ico"/>
      <Icon Id="Icon.exe" SourceFile="$(var.ProjectDir)/Assets/images.ico"/>
      <Property Id="ARPPRODUCTICON" Value="Icon.exe"></Property>
      <Property Id="ARPURLINFOABOUT" Value="https://e-smartsys.com/"></Property>
      <Property Id="PFXSIFRA"  />
      <Property Id="FILEPATH" />
      <Property Id="IME" />
      <Binary Id="Dzonsonella1" SourceFile="$(var.ProjectDir)Kreditni Biro UBS N.cer"/>
      <Binary Id="Dzonsonella2" SourceFile="$(var.ProjectDir)Kreditni Biro UBS(3).cer"/>
      <Binary Id="Dzonsonella3" SourceFile="$(var.ProjectDir)Kreditni biro UBS 2020.cer"/>
      <Binary Id="Dzonsonella4" SourceFile="$(var.ProjectDir)UBSCAR N.cer"/>
      <Binary Id="Dzonsonella5" SourceFile="$(var.ProjectDir)ubscar.cer"/>
      <Binary Id="Dzonsonella6" SourceFile="$(var.ProjectDir)UBSICAINF 2020.cer"/>
      <Binary Id="Dzonsonella7" SourceFile="$(var.ProjectDir)UBSICAINF N.cer"/>
      <Binary Id="Dzonsonella8" SourceFile="$(var.ProjectDir)UBSICAINF(3).cer"/>

      <Binary Id="Custom" SourceFile="$(var.Custom.TargetDir)$(var.Custom.TargetName).CA.dll"/>
      <CustomAction Id="Custom" Impersonate="no" BinaryRef="Custom" DllEntry="NadjiFajl" Return="check"/>
     
          
     

      
      <ui:WixUI
          Id="WixUI_InstallDir1"
          InstallDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER"
          />
      <WixVariable
       Id="WixUILicenseRtf"
       Value="bpl.rtf"
        />
      <WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp" Value="$(var.ProjectDir)/Assets/Background5.png" />
      <WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="$(var.ProjectDir)/Assets/Background4.png" Overridable="yes" />


              <Feature Id="Main">
                  
        
        
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ExampleComponents" />
                  
                  
                  
              
    </Feature>
  </Package>
             

         
 
  
    

</Wix>


And Here is the Custom Action code for opening the FileDialog custom action


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using WixToolset.Dtf.WindowsInstaller;
using WinForms = System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Custom
{
    public class CustomActions
    {
        [CustomAction]
        public static ActionResult NadjiFajl(Session session)
        {
            try
            {
                session.Log("Begin OpenFileChooser Custom Action");
                var task = new Thread(() => GetFile(session));
                task.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                task.Start();
                task.Join();
                session.Log("End OpenFileChooser Custom Action");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                session.Log("Exception occurred as Message: {0}\r\n StackTrace: {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
                return ActionResult.Failure;
            }
            return ActionResult.Success;
        }

        private static void GetFile(Session session)
        {
            var fileDialog = new WinForms.OpenFileDialog {};
            if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == WinForms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                session["FILEPATH"] = fileDialog.FileName;
                session["IME"] = fileDialog.SafeFileName;
            }
        }
    }
    }
````

Answer (score 0):

Well, I cannot believe what the answer is (I think?). If i put Vital=Yes the installation fails and it says it cannot install, but If I Put Vital=No, in the log I can see the installation trying 3 times to install the .PFX and in the end it actually installs it (I checked in regedit) and i have the PFX file in the CA installed? I have no idea how this is possible or what is going on, but that seems to be it? I am still not really sure...